# How to solve the problem of css block dropping out when making a website page?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

When making an adaptive web page the child block "falls out" of the parent block. The entire page is shifted some distance to the left, and an empty bar appears on the right, which moves all the content.
I need to put all content in the correct place.

I've tried setting the block width to 100%, but it still gets larger than the parent block.

When making a web page, I used bootstrap v5.1.3, maybe the problem is in some properties in it that override the set width of my block?

Comment: Post a [mcve] and read on [ask]

Comment: It's very hard to simply guess what the answer might be. Please edit your post any HTML and CSS that you're using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using the bootstrap 4. I wanted to make offset sections on the page, for this I used the “row” and “col” classes, but they got out of the parent block.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJgf1.jpg)

If you look at the picture, you can see that bootstrap does have built-in class indentation (strikethrough now).

To redefine them in the section itself, change the margin to the one you need.

```
<section class="row **m-0**">
        <div class="col-3  brown-background **p-0**"></div>
        <ul class="col white-background list-without-point p-0 m-0">
            <li class="row align-items-center **m-5**">
                //smth here
            </li>
            <li class="row **m-5** align-items-center">
                // smth here
            </li>
            <li class="row **m-5** align-items-center">
                // smth here
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

If I understood the problem correctly, this might be the solution.